# Recaptcha cant get response in angular after changing page

Tags: angularjs, forms, recaptcha

I have a problem with my angular application. I have a register page on my site. Normally when I get straight to the register page it works fine, after submitting the form is sent and user is registered. Problem appears when I for example load register page then go to login page and then again to register. In this case the form is not sent to server. 
I tried to figure it out and even to repair by refreshing page after clicking register link but it didn't help.

I debug my application a little and found that it's recaptcha causing my problem. I use angular-recaptcha version 2.2.5; Tried to log the output of vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() but nothing showed in console.

Here is some code, where the problem may lay:

Request of form

```
$scope.registerRequest = (form) => {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity');
    if (!form.$valid) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.formData.reCaptcha = vcRecaptchaService.getResponse();

    apiRequest.post('user/register', $scope.formData).success((response) => {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $scope.registered = true;
        $scope.formData = {};
    });
};
```

Routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => {
$routeProvider
        .when('/auth/login', {
            controller: 'authLogin',
            label: 'Logowanie',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/authLoginView.html',
            access: ['UNAUTH']
        })
        .when('/auth/register/', {
            controller: 'authRegister',
            label: 'Rejestracja',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/authRegisterView.html',
            access: ['UNAUTH']
        })
        .when('/auth/register/confirm', {
            controller: 'authRegister',
            label: 'Potwierdzenie rejestracji',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/authRegisterView.html',
            access: ['UNAUTH']
        })
        .when('/auth/register/resend', {
            controller: 'authRegister',
            label: 'Rejestracja',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/authRegisterView.html',
            access: ['UNAUTH']
        })
}]);
```

And some HTML:

```
<div ng-if="section == 'register'" class="container employer-container">
    <form name="registerForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" loader is-loading="isLoading">
        <h4 class="employer-h4">Rejestracja</h4>

        <p class="bg-success text-success col-xs-12" ng-show="registered">
            Użytkownik został zarejestrowany. Na podany adres e-mail wysłaliśmy dalsze instrukcje.
        </p>

        <div ng-hide="registered">
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">E-mail:</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail"
                           ng-model="formData.email" name="username"
                           ng-required="true">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Hasło:</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Hasło"
                           ng-model="formData.password" name="password" ng-minlength="5"
                           ng-required="true" equals="{{ formData.confirmPassword }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-md-3 control-label">Powtórz hasło:</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło"
                           ng-model="formData.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" ng-minlength="5"
                           ng-required="true" equals="{{ formData.password }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="userType">Rodzaj konta:</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control"
                                id="userType" name="userType" dropdown-toggle ng-model="formData.userType"
                                ng-required="true">
                            {{ userTypes[formData.userType] || 'rodzaj konta' }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li ng-repeat="(key, userType) in userTypes">
                                <a href="" ng-click="$parent.formData.userType = key">{{ ::userType }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="acceptTerms" ng-model="formData.acceptedTerms" name="acceptTerms" ng-required="true">
                    <label class="control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="acceptTerms">Zgadzam się z  <a href="/#!/page/4" style="color: #3C5B9B;">Regulaminem</a></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="acceptTerms2" ng-model="formData.acceptedTerms2" name="acceptTerms2" ng-required="true">
                    <label class="control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="acceptTerms2">Wyrażam zgodę na przetwarzanie moich danych w celu realizacji usług w ramach Serwisu i akceptuję <a href="/#!/page/5" style="color: #3C5B9B;">Politykę Prywatności.</a>.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="acceptTerms3" ng-model="formData.acceptedTerms3" name="acceptTerms3" ng-required="true">
                    <label class="control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="acceptTerms3">Wyrażam zgodę na przetwarzanie moich danych w <a href="/#!/page/9" style="color: #3C5B9B;">celach marketingowych.</a></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div vc-recaptcha key="'key'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <a href="#!/auth/lostpassword">Zapomniane hasło</a> |
                    <a href="#!/auth/login">Logowanie</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="registerRequest(registerForm)">Zarejestruj</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Problem could be seen here: http://pze2.biuro.netivo.pl/

Answering to one of questions about ['UNAUTH'] in my routes. It is for allowing only users who are not logged in to enter this page.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [ask] using [mcve]

Comment: @Manveru, I am not asnwering your post but have query for you. Can you please tell what is the use of `access: ['UNAUTH']` in your route cofig

Comment: have you tried passing the id of the recaptcha widget to the getResponse call? I think when you change routes your widget is getting destroyed, and the recaptcha code isn't getting the new widget id.

Comment: @Vinny No I haven't tried this, any idea how to do this?  I'am totally new in angular.

Comment: Not entirely sure as I haven't used this recaptcha library/plugin, but I think the getResponse function wants the id of the dom element. So getresponse("key"). Look up their github page for more info on the optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Vinny I managed to solve the problem.

The problem lies as he said in reCaptcha.getResponse() not getting right widget.

For those who will have same problem I put the solution in my code:

Request:

```
$scope.registerRequest = (form) => {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity');
    if (!form.$valid) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.isLoading = true;

    apiRequest.post('user/register', $scope.formData).success((response) => {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $scope.registered = true;
        $scope.formData = {};
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="section == 'register'" class="container employer-container">
    <form name="registerForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" loader is-loading="isLoading">
        <h4 class="employer-h4">Rejestracja</h4>

        <p class="bg-success text-success col-xs-12" ng-show="registered">
            Użytkownik został zarejestrowany. Na podany adres e-mail wysłaliśmy dalsze instrukcje.
        </p>
        <div ng-hide="registered">
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div vc-recaptcha ng-model="formData.reCaptcha" key="'key'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <a href="#!/auth/lostpassword">Zapomniane hasło</a> |
                    <a href="#!/auth/login">Logowanie</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="registerRequest(registerForm)">Zarejestruj</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```